# Access is denied Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-service-fabric

I'm using the code below in a Stateless Microsoft service fabric service to host a .net core self host MVC application, unfortunately when I run the code below I get the error "Access is denied" when the Start() method is called.

If I switch to using Kestrel instead of the WebListener, then it is fine.  If I move the code to a standard console app (i.e. not using service fabric) it is fine.

How can I get this to work with the WebListener?

```
            _host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseUrls(listeningAddress)
                .UseServer("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener")
                .UseContentRoot(wwwroot)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            //                    .UseKestrel()

            _host.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually got this to work by using the core rc2 release and the UseWebListener extension, rather than the UseServer extension

Comment: UseServer is going away anyways... https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/commit/14557f01311a72f0cca9ac57e5063057297b3bb5

Answer (score 1):

You may have an issue with urlacls:
`netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:443/ user=Everyone`

I currently have some SF stuff which needs that urlacl set up when it hits the OWIN Startup method, lest it throw Access Denied in the event log and some unhelpful errors about not being able to find the OWIN Startup class, and then some stuff in IIS which gives me 503 errors when it's set up. So I am deploying SF stuff, and then running `netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:443/` before my IIS stuff.